# API to access vehicle information

Tags: api

I was wondering if there is an API for accessing vehicle information and various events that occur?  I am guessing that if I want that type of information, I'd have to work directly with the manufacturer to get access to that information.

Walter

Comment: I beg to differ ... computers are embedded in cars.  When was the last time you ridden in a car with a mechanical link to the gas pedal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technology is called an On Board Diagnostics port [OBD2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics) and it exists in most modern cars.  A quick google search for OBD2 + java turned up some interesting results.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what I'm looking for.  I think it could be fun to play around with, provided my car still runs.